# 12.04 on Pentium Dual Core with 1GB or ram running slow

Tags: 12.04, hardware-test

hey i have a Lenovo Thinkpad Laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. 
It runs slow. I tried "System profiler and Benchmark" to test the computer. but the application quits and closes after the first few benchmark test. before it even gets to the other tests. 
So i tried "Hardinfo" that installed on the Puppy Linux live cd. that did the same thing (the apps look just a like).
the memory usage isnt the problem on this pc. its the cpu processes. just running the "system profiler" app that comes with ubuntu uses about 34% on each core, default with nothing running its 5-10% on each core. 
i cant really find what the deal is other than that ubuntu is a cpu hog. 
so im testing unity2D at the moment to see how it goes. 
if you have any other suggestions, feel free to answer this question.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu would be a better alternative.

Honestly, I would go for a very specific install with a tiny distro, or probably ubuntu minimal disc to avoid any unnecessary packaged that would make the life hard for you hardware; consider using a window & file manager double instead of a full desktop enviroment.

Comment: Almost anything but unity or gnome, kde or xfce would work as well.

Comment: No, even tho it is written in QT KDE cannot be considered light. Maybe KDE's window manager?

Also yes, Xfce is a pretty alternative.

Comment: KDE works well on the hardware I use that does not run well with Unity or gnome-shell. It is a trade off between features and speed and kubuntu is certainly lighter then Unity.

Comment: I guess unity complicated so much, KDE become light. I remember that my old computer running smooth with gnome interfaced ubuntu while the opensuse with kde making problem but that may be caused of slackware too. Did you try working with only window and file manager environment, it sure feels like flying.

Comment: My gentoo install uses openbox + tint2 and uses about 60 MB RAM after log in http://bodhizazen.net/img/Linux/gentoo.png

Comment: I'm sure it is using less than your KDE setup.